# Using prepared queries to change the column in a MySQL update command Python 3.5

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write a function that takes 3 values, the column to edit, the value to insert, and the id of the row (a hash in this case). However I get a standard "There's an error on your SQL Syntax"

```
def _alter_material_prop(self, hash, key, val):
    sql = "UPDATE `materials` SET "+key+" = %s WHERE `materials`.`hashkey` = %s"
    self.cursor.execute(sql, (val, hash))
    self.db.commit()
```

This is my sql injectable code that functions.

Here is how I would like to do it:

```
def _alter_material_prop(self, hash, key, val):
    sql = "UPDATE `materials` SET %s = %s WHERE `materials`.`hashkey` = %s"
    self.cursor.execute(sql, (key, val, hash))
    self.db.commit()
```

But this gives the following error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Nate/PycharmProjects/mofdb-insert-mofs/mofdb_interface_tests.py", line 478, in test_alter_mat_prop
    mofdb._alter_material_prop(hashkey, "PLD", 1337.0)
  File "/Users/Nate/PycharmProjects/mofdb-insert-mofs/mofdb_interface.py", line 227, in _alter_material_prop
    self.cursor.execute(sql, (key, val, hash))
  File "/Users/Nate/PycharmProjects/mofdb-insert-mofs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 559, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Users/Nate/PycharmProjects/mofdb-insert-mofs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 494, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Users/Nate/PycharmProjects/mofdb-insert-mofs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 396, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''PLD' = 1337.0 WHERE `materials`.`hashkey` = '43ba34f38db8ec0f20cb058853275535ea' at line 1
```

Comment: Hi Nate, there may be an issue with your design. Generally, column names are not supposed to be prepared the way you want. An end user who may submit malicious inputs should not need to know the column names in your table.

Comment: @Bryan okay so this is just not supported for prepared queries? This projects assumes a technically competent friendly user so I'm not worried about them messing with an improper column.

Comment: what you are trying to do is not supported for prepared queries. I would recommend seeing if you can redesign your code in a way does not require you to prepare the column names.

Comment: @Bryan Okay thanks, I'll just parsed the column name arg and use if/elif to call a different prepared query based on that. (Practical with only 4 columns)